# openvino model "age-gender-recognition-retail-0013.xml" for child identification

Tags: python, opencv, intel, face-recognition, openvino

is it possible to add on age-gender-recognition-retail-0013 model to identify children age on openvino? If so, how can I retrain the model to make it able to identify the children age. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [age-gender-recognition-retail-0013](https://docs.openvino.ai/2022.1/omz_models_model_age_gender_recognition_retail_0013.html) is able to recognize age of people in [18, 75] years old range, it is not applicable for children since their faces were not in the training set.

Intel’s Pre-Trained Models are available in Open Model Zoo as Intermediate Representation (IR) format. The non-IR versions of pretrained models are not publicly provided, hence they cannot be used for retraining purpose.